# Emacs Dired Behavior

Tags: emacs, dired

I have used emacs for years and am accustomed to having emacs open a selected file in the same window that dired is executed in.  In recent revisions, when dired is executed  with say 2 windows open, the file selected will be displayed in the alternate window from dired.  How can I set up emacs to use the same window to display the file as died (allowing me to look at two files simultaneously--the way emacs used to work)?

Comment: What "recent revision" exactly do you use? I'm using 23.1 and pressing return (bound to `dired-advertised-find-file`) has the behaviour you're asking for. To get the behaviour you see, I have to press o (bound to `dired-find-file-other-window`).

Comment: I can only affirm what Rört is saying. Try `emacs -Q` to see whether a "blank" emacs has the behaviour you described.

Answer (score 8):

As per the comments above, check <kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>k</kbd><kbd>RET</kbd> when in dired to see what <kbd>RET</kbd> is bound to (or similarly if you are using another key).

`dired-find-file` uses `switch-to-buffer` which could cause the buffer to open in another window:

> If the selected window is the minibuffer window or dedicated to
>   its buffer, use `pop-to-buffer' for displaying the buffer.

That seems less likely to be the issue, though.

edit: Ah, you're using the mouse. It's often good to explicitly say that in questions about Emacs, because most Emacs users rarely touch the mouse.

The same answer applies, however: From dired, type <kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>k</kbd> and then the 'key'-binding you are using (in this case clicking mouse button 1), which tells us:

> ----------------- up-event (short click) ----------------
>
> <mouse-1> at that spot is remapped to <mouse-2>, which runs the
>   command dired-mouse-find-file-other-window, which is an interactive
>   compiled Lisp function in `dired.el'.
>
> (dired-mouse-find-file-other-window EVENT)
>
> In Dired, visit the file or directory name you click on.

There's no default `dired-mouse-find-file` function for some reason, but the following will fake it:

```
(add-hook 'dired-mode-hook 'my-dired-mode-hook)
(defun my-dired-mode-hook ()
  (local-set-key (kbd "<mouse-2>") 'dired-mouse-find-file))

(defun dired-mouse-find-file (event)
  "In Dired, visit the file or directory name you click on."
  (interactive "e")
  (require 'cl)
  (flet ((find-file-other-window
          (filename &optional wildcards)
          (find-file filename wildcards)))
    (dired-mouse-find-file-other-window event)))
```

Comment: The Emacs version I am using is 23.2.1.  Also, if a file is select with mouse-1 when two windows are open, it will display the file in the other window.  Thanks for your comments.

Comment: I think this is the problem.  Depending upon what I am doing I often use the mouse to position the cursor to the file in  dired that I will operate on.  Mouse button 1 is now bound to (find-file-other-window). I think this is new in recent versions of Emacs; but, I am not sure as old versions not on my systems.  Thanks for all the help.  I think I can resolve it now that the problem is understood.

Comment: FWIW, I had already added some elisp which resolves the issue. (Maybe S.O. doesn't notify users about edits to answers to their questions?)

Answer (score 5):

Pressing Enter key on a file in dired opens the file in the same window.  Pressing `o` on a file in dired opens it in other-window.  Are you sure you are not rebinding these keys in your .emacs?

Comment: There are no bindings set.  I usually use "f" visit a file in dired.

Comment: Well, what dooes `C-h k f` in dired mode show?  on mine it is `(dired-find-file)`.  Unless it(f key in dired mode) is bound to `(dired-find-file-other-window)`, I don't see why dired opens the file in a new window.

Comment: "f" is bound to (dired-find-file)

Comment: Does `emacs -qQ` behave the same way?  If it does not, there is something in your settings.