# Emacs open directory

Tags: emacs

Emacs allows opening a directory and choosing files. After going one step up or down in the directory, the control moves to another split window. My problem how to make the control in same window?

Given this also how to open files in specific split windows?

Comment: Typing `a` in dired effectively *replaces* the current buffer with the selected file or directory, so you don't end up with multiple dired buffers.

Comment: Your comments suggest you want to use the mouse, in which case the following might be relevant? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5180496/emacs-dired-behavior/5181764

Answer (score 1):

If you are using `dired`, you can use <kbd>^</kbd> to include an upward directory and <kbd>i</kbd> to include a subdirectory. Jump between directory entries with <kbd><</kbd> and <kbd>></kbd>.

Comment: sorry I am new and don't get this?

Comment: I need the mouse to do this for me. How can I tell the .emacs such thing. Also the line numbers still dont show even I edited the .emacs file!

Answer (score 1):

In `dired-mode`, you can press <kbd>i</kbd> (`dired-maybe-insert-subdir`) while point is over a directory to insert that directory's contents into the same buffer (rather than opening a new buffer).

In a buffer with multiple directories open, press <kbd>C-M-p</kbd> (`dired-prev-subdir`) while point is in an opened subdirectory to jump up to previous directories in the buffer.

You mentioned you wanted to insert subdirectories into the dired buffer with a right click. Here's some code to do that:

```
(add-hook 'dired-mode-hook
          (lambda ()
            (local-set-key [mouse-3]
                           (lambda (click)
                             (interactive "e")
                             (goto-char (posn-point (event-start click)))
                             (call-interactively #'dired-maybe-insert-subdir)))))
```

Comment: I want to make the mouse right act like this. can I edit the .emacs somehow?